# Transition from academia to the world of finance

Tags: career-path

I am a research associate in Pure Mathematics at one of the four best universities in the UK, with publication track record excelling most (all?) of my friends who are at a similar stage of their career. I am fairly known in my field (which is in pure maths, though), yet I was unable to secure an academic position for the next year.

I feel exhausted of the never-ending chase for non-existent academic positions and I am sure that this is the right moment to leave the academic community.

I have some vague insterest in banking and finance but for obvious reasons I have never studied it being too focused on high-quality research in Pure Maths. Hence my question:

> What are the most common places in the UK (companies, jobs, etc.) concerning finance/banking/audit where failed academic like myself often end up?

Do the big insitutions hire ex-acadmics or should I apply in the similar way as my former students (I was a temporary lecturer too)? This would be strange as in the past I was writing support statements for them. Who would write one for me?

Comment: This might not be a suitable question for academia stackexchange, because is about another job market.

Comment: *...in the past I was writing support statements for them.* -- Any chance you can contact some of these students and use them as a foot in the door? Sounds like an amazing networking opportunity.

Comment: I don't understand the "Do the big institutions..." question.  For your main question, generally you can apply to investment firms, banks, insurance companies, ...  They look for people at various academic levels.  E.g., one of my friends after a math postdoc got a job at Lloyds of London.

Comment: I met one person who had been in a similar situation and got a job at a small hedge fund (in London, of course). He said that for people like him, with no experience in finance, small companies are definitely easier to get in to than big ones. I think he said his company does slow-paced research-type work and hired many people with PhDs. Other advice: you will need to have a genuine interest in banking/finance, which can be demonstrated by having some knowledge and being able to talk about the industry or finance/economic news, not just a vague interest.

Comment: To be honest, academia is crap now, and I'm also searching for such alternative.